# Cross-platform User-friendly Sync tools

Tags: sync, language, gui, cross-platform

> **Similar question for Windows users:**
>   [Keeping folders synced between several machines](https://superuser.com/questions/349/keeping-folders-synced-between-several-machines)

I need a cross-platform sync tool with reasonably simple GUI interface (so I can teach non-expert users how to use it).

My requirements are:

- tool works the same in Windows and Linux
- and supports bi-directional syncing
- and syncs local folders as well as over the network (network syncing may be platform-specific)
- and is capable of advanced file comparison (checksums) as well as quick one (mtime)
- and has a simple GUI (single windows, two panel)
- and is available in languages other than English (or can be easily translated)
- and works reasonably fast on large syncs (does not hang nor crash)

I tried

- Unison. GUI is too unnatural and too foreign for Windows users. I don't believe I can teach non-experts users to use it. Only in English. Seems to be rather unresponsive (user interface issue).
- DeltaCopy (Rsync windows service). It is not bidirectional and mostly intended for non-interactive syncing. Only in English.
- JFileSync and DirSync. No translations. One of the two was crashing on huge syncs (I don't remember which one).

Is there anything else?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of #349. #349 is about non-interactive windows-specific tools. This question is about interactive *cross-platform* tools with easy interface.

Comment: After 3 months you still don't have an answer? Even if it is re-opened it will be closed as no longer relevant. Furthermore, 3 of the items listed in the duplicate is **cross platform**. Don't let the Windows tag fool you.

Comment: IMO, closing a question because it doesn't have an answer, is not the right thing. It means it won't be answered ever. Out of items listed in #349, only Dropbox seems relevant and actually cross-platform, but it is not suitable for local syncing. Also absolutely different requirements in #349 mean it will attract more non-relevant answers. Please leave this question open. I still hope someone writes or founds an appropriate tool and mentions it here.

Comment: Are we going to go around in circles? This is a duplicate question, older then 3 months, which has been viewed 100 times, generate 2 answers with up-votes, and both products are mentioned as answers to the duplicate question. SU is **not** a forum. It's a Q&A site with a strict policy on only allowing one question for a particular need. The next logical step would be to delete this question.

Comment: This question is **not** an exact duplicate. It asks about *different* kind of tools for *different* platforms. SU is not a forum, but I hope it is not a *Windows-only* Q&A site. BTW, this question cannot attract attention or collect answers while it remains closed.

Answer (score 3):

[Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com) works well on Mac, Windows and Linux.

Allows you to automatically sync entire directories with many machines over the internet.

[Microsoft Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) is also very good but I think is just Mac and Windows. (although Linux users can use the web site, but not full on sync)

Comment: Does it allow two-way syncing between two _local_ folders? (E.g. internal disk and an external disk?). What about translations?

Comment: No, I think both are for syncing cross computer, not for a single computer.

Answer (score 1):

[SyncToy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy) would match to most of points (especially user-friendliness, from my point of view), but it's a Windows-only tool.

So, of course, it won't match to the "cross-platform" condition. I'm mentioning it mostly as a reference. Ideally, we would need to find a similar tool, working under linux.

Comment: I have used SyncToy on Windows systems to sync over to a Samba share on a Linux system, it works great.

Comment: Well, probably it may work SyncToy + Samba share for windows and something else and the same share for Linux... Thanks!