# Windows 8 folder to folder sync software

Tags: windows, sync, windows-live-mesh, onedrive

I'm looking for direct folder to folder synchronization in Windows 8.  I was previously using Live Mesh to accomplish this, but now it looks like that is no longer an option.

Note that I'm talking about direct folder to folder sync between different computers, not syncing to the cloud.  I'm aware of products like Google Drive, SkyDrive, Dropbox, etc.  The problem with them is the space limitation.

Basically, I was syncing important files before between my desktop and all of my laptops.  One folder for example is My Pictures.  This folder has almost 40 gigs of files, which is why the options listed above are not going to work for me.

Just need direct syncing, nothing stored on the cloud.  I was told by a Microsoft employee that SkyDrive would be replacing Mesh and would provide all the same functionality.  So far this looks to be completely false, since the ability to remote desktop is gone along with folder to folder sync.  Unless I'm just missing something?

Comment: Note that Cubby's P2P sync function is now in the paid tier of service.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you try Microsoft Sync Toy which should suffice your requirements?

[Microsoft SyncToy:](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=15155)

> SyncToy 2.1 is a free application that synchronizes files and folders
>   between locations. Typical uses include sharing files, such as photos,
>   with other computers and creating backup copies of files and folders.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in Windows 8.  Tells me I need to first install .NET framework, despite the fact that .NET framework comes bundled with Win8.

Comment: Looks like you need to install .NET 3.5 even though Windows 8 comes bundled with 4. More details here: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/is/synctoy/thread/6752827a-d0e3-41c0-9ae4-d3c08efbe629

Comment: Personally I use Allway Sync for last 3 years. http://allwaysync.com/

Comment: Is it still the case with SyncToy that syncing only works if the computers are on the same LAN, and one of the computers has to share the folder(s) to be synced, so the other can access them?

Comment: probably needs to be on the same LAN but just use hamachi to solve that.

Comment: I successfully ran it on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4):

You can use Live Mesh on Windows 8. You have to look for Windows Essentials 2011 package from where you'll download Mesh.

Comment: For future people who find this: Live Mesh is being turned off by Microsoft on February 13th, 2013 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mesh-devices-sync-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Best replacement for Live Mesh I've found so far is [Cubby](https://www.cubby.com). While it doesn't offer remote desktop (for that you can try other [LogMeIn products](https://secure.logmein.com/EU/welcome/products)), it does offer PC-to-PC sync of an arbitrary number of folders. It's currently in closed beta, but you can sign up for an invite.

[image]

Comment: Powered by LogMeIn? Sounds promising. Signed up for an invite.

Comment: If you already have a LogMeIn account cubby.com/download appears to allow you to install and use the app without an invite.

Comment: DirectSync is not part of the free product.  The free sync provided by Cubby requires space in their cloud, also not free, past 5gb.

Comment: @DonSimon This answer was posted before Cubby's pricing scheme was announced. Also, the original question didn't specify that the solution had to be free, so this answer is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the similar question - [How do I synchronise two folders in real-time in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/65524/how-do-i-synchronise-two-folders-in-real-time-in-windows-7)

I tried the [DSyncronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) and it works well in Windows 8