# How can I keep two folders synchronized when a new file is created in one of them on Windows?

Tags: windows, gaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do synchronize two folders in Windows 7 in real-time?](https://superuser.com/questions/65524/how-do-synchronize-two-folders-in-windows-7-in-real-time)

I got a dedicated server with Windows Server 2008 OS, which I am hosting game servers off.

Now, for one of the games, it creates a file which has to be downloaded to the players that join each time the server restarts. We have enabled Fast Download which means that the files are hosted off of web hosting, which enables the players to download at max speed while if they had to download the files through the game server itself, the speed is set to maximum of 20 KB / sec which cannot be changed. Now, for ease of use, I'd like to automatically synchronize the game server cache folder (which is where the file is created) with the web hosting folder (It's hosted off of the same machine) once the new file is created.

Are there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use robocopy as it can monitor the folders (from Windows 7 and 2008). It is the updated version of Xcopy really, but has more flexibility. It also only copies files which are different and to prevent copying the same data across.

/MON:n : MONitor source; run again when more than n changes seen.
/MOT:m : MOnitor source; run again in m minutes Time, if changed.

More details (and too many to post into this answer): http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

```
Robocopy c:\sales c:\salesbu *.xls /mon:1
```

**Edit**

The robocopy monitor is not 'foolproof' by any means.  If you really want some real-time monitoring solution, you may need to write a script to do so. Also, see [How do I synchronise two folders in real-time in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/65524/how-do-synchronize-two-folders-in-windows-7-in-real-time)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!  Are there any way to make it instant? Currently, there are 1 minute interval between copying. Because if the cache file isn't downloaded, the player gets an error.

Comment: @Tom - Determine the reason a cache file has to be downloaded each time a server is restarted.  This seems odd.  the `/mon:1` is the 1 minute delay.

Comment: @Ramhound, Well, the error caused can crash the game for the player. So if the player, in any way, is abled to join the server before the cache file has been copied, his game can crash and might even overload the computer because that cache file is so important for the game to even run. I got it to work with Dsynchronize though. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom, I admit I don't fully understand, but surely you should have things in place which ensures all processes are complete/ready before you let people join. It sounds like your proposal is very fail-dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [Windows 7 "Offline Files"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Understanding-offline-files) feature, as mentioned in [this comment](http://lifehacker.com/5893547/how-can-i-sync-my-files-without-having-to-store-them-online?comment=48094644#comments) to a related Lifehacker article titled *How Can I Sync My Files Without Having To Store Them Online?* which suggests using it to quickly sync multiple files between multiple computers.