# Set dropbox to only use LAN sync (dont allow web sync)

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to set Dropbox to only use LAN sync and compeltly ignore the external web sync - ie. back to the server and then the server pushses the changes to the other machines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is not possible. (There is a workaraound, see below.)

"Lan Sync" only **begins to work** when the file is uploaded to the Dropbox-servers. There it can be evaluated who can get the file via "LAN Sync".

If you drop a file in the Dropbox-folder on a workstation the file is not yet known to the Dropbox-servers. It first needs to be uploaded to the Dropbox-servers before the transfer via your LAN can begin. After uploading to Dropbox your file *if possible* **will** be transferred  via LAN to your server (but that's not what you wanted).

**Workaround**:
The only way this could work (somewhat similar to what you want) is if you **share** the Dropbox-folder on the server within your network and the users drop files in that shared folder (directly on the server). Then, after uploading it to the Dropbox-server, it will be transferred via "LAN Sync" back to all your workstations.

They just need to know not to use their local Dropbox-folder when connected to the server (because otherwise the local Dropbox begins uploading again). I assume these are laptops who are often disconnected from the network because otherwise there would be no need for the Dropbox-client on the workstation because you already shared it via the server.

Comment: This is incorrect (or presumably maybe was correct back 2013). With Lan Sync Dropbox does not need to upload the file first to Dropbox as that would defeat the purpose of Lan Sync. It syncs the meta data to Dropbox servers but is able to sync the actual files directly to the other computer. https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2015/10/inside-lan-sync/

Comment: @cchiera The fact meta data from a non-existing file is shared within the network (and subsequently a Lan sync is started) is news to me. Thnx. I'm not sure it was the case in 2013. I should try this the next time I get 2 computers in 1 network. But for the answer to the original question... it is still a big no. You still need a connection to the Dropbox server. And the question was if you could sync without *allowing* web sync (which is not possible). I've always experienced that Lan sync kicks in for completely uploaded files but I'll try this the next time I come across a compatible setup.

Answer (score 4):

Other alternatives that allow for local syncing without the cloud are:

[BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync)

> Device to device.
>   Skip the cloud.
>   Fast, private file sharing for teams and individuals.

[SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/)

> SparkleShare creates a special folder on your computer. You can add remotely hosted folders (or "projects") to this folder. These projects will be automatically kept in sync with both the host and all of your peers when someone adds, removes or edits a file.

Comment: When recommending software, please [follow these guidelines](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225).

Comment: DSynchronize might also be a good option. It supports LAN sync and has received many upvotes in this question https://superuser.com/questions/65524/how-do-i-synchronise-two-folders-in-real-time-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Old question but as I am in the same situation, by googling I ended up here. I have found a Dropbox alternative that does exactly that - you can either sync with the cloud, just over LAN or both - [Cubby from LogMeIn](http://www.cubby.com) seems to do the job.

the only problem I've encountered so far is that it makes my file server's processor overheat during LAN syncing (but it's a 2006 dual core laptop with a tired fan).

Answer (score 0):

Anther open source alternative is syncthing. Its pretty cool. Dont need a central server and can be setup in a number of different configure way. However I also found it somewhat slow and a bit buggy and endup moving back to dropbox after about a year of use.

https://syncthing.net/

Answer (score -2):

dont know if previous answers are wrong or just outdated so:

LAN Sync begins syncing devices on the same network first, and then uploading to the internet. - See more at: http://www.dropboxtips.com/enable-lan-sync-for-superfast-local-transfers/#sthash.t8PF0PkJ.dpuf

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link within you answer. Thanks.