# Does winscp remote real-time synch work for giant directories ( > 30GB)

Tags: sync, winscp

I am trying out the information provided at:

- [How do I synchronise two folders in real-time in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/a/393525/216440)
- [Synchronize Files in Realtime from a Windows PC to a Linux Box](http://blog.jordanhopfner.com/2012/09/13/synchronize-files-in-realtime-from-a-windows-pc-to-a-test-linux-box/)

So far I am seeing the following:

```
Connecting to 192.168.2.69 ...
Connected with 192.168.2.69. Waiting for welcome message...
Connected
Starting the session...
Reading remote directory...
Session started.
Active session: [1] NAS
Watching for changes, press Ctrl-C to abort...
Scanning 'D:\_DOCS' for subdirectories...
```

I've tried Rebit to synch my docs with my NAS in real time but was completely disappointed.

Now I am trying WinSCP but don't know how good it is, and whether it can handle syncing giant directories.

Comment: Almost certainly not.  Almost nothing can do a good job syncing at the filesystem level in real time.

Comment: @Zoredache so RAID (either software or hardware) is basically the way to go... ?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not about total file size. But rather about total number of (sub)directories.

And of course it's about performance of your system. It's OS-level service that watches for changes in directories, not WinSCP itself.

And also about frequency of the changes. WinSCP synchronizes them in a sequence, so you cannot make more changes than WinSCP can possibly upload in real-time.

For me WinSCP works just fine watching few tens of thousands directories. Just for an idea (although it does not really matter), that's about few hundreds of thousands files and over 600 GiB.

*Also note the `Unknown switch 'filemask'` error in your script output. There's something wrong. You are possibly using some old version of WinSCP.*