# Windows 7, can I mirror directories when I got one HHD? (like RAID)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid

In Windows 7, lets say I have a "works" directory which containts my work, personal etc information. I want to use a program which always checks the disk and make mirror(s) of this directory. Something like a RAID technology. How can I do that? Thats important, I have now bad sectors....

Comment: Your question is possibly already answered here: [How do I synchronise two folders in real-time in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/65524/how-do-i-synchronise-two-folders-in-real-time-in-windows-7). If it doesn't answer your question, please point out why. Otherwise it may be closes as a duplicate.

Comment: and does it watch the original directory + mirrored one(s) in the background?

Comment: That’s what real-time means. This does not protect you from silent data corruption, however. Get a new disk.

Comment: "RAID" is only useful if you have more than one disk, since that's what it's all about. :) You are describing folder synchronizing.

Answer (score 1):

Use somthing as freefilesync to mirror a directory http://www.freefilesync.org/

Comment: and does it watch the original directory + mirrored one(s) in the background?

Comment: Yes. It replicate all modifications to the mirrored one. And can maintain previous versions for backup purpose. There are other utilities too. This is another one: DSynchronize: http://dimio.altervista.org/ita/