# Sync two folder (2 way sync) in one windows machine in realtime

Tags: windows, git, sync

I am searching for a solution how to keep sync two folders, in same machine.
It can be something very simple. But it must always keep the last changes files, on all folders.

I am thought maybe it can be done using bat files, but I didn't found yet a solution.

There is no, `source` or `destinatin` all the folders are sources, and destination. I want it to always keep the last modified version.

(It must to not be symbolic link, or junction, or else, because git broke them in checkouts...)

I have read:
[How do I synchronise two folders in real-time in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/65524/how-do-i-synchronise-two-folders-in-real-time-in-windows-7)

But the software there are not stand exactly with the requiments I need.

Thank you

Comment: The answers to the question you refer to name about ten possible software packages which aim to do what you need. To which of them do you refer when you say they don't meet your requirements, and in what regard?

Comment: Dsynchonice cannot do it.
Synkron is very old.
WinSCP is something else.
Yadis is one way sync

Comment: So you need two folders to always have identical content - at all times? Why? Any automated system will do this, but any "broken" files will also sync... that's just like using RAID1... RAID1 mirrors the disks... one error = same error on both disks... Can you explain a bit more to clarify?

Comment: Is not for backup. Which autmated system you know for that?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Without installing anything.
Just need to create a schedule task, than run every 10 minutes.

For each folder I am dong that:

```
robocopy folder1  folder2  /r:1 /w:2 /xo
robocopy folder2  folder1 /r:1 /w:2 /xo

robocopy folder1  folder3  /r:1 /w:2 /xo
robocopy folder1  folder4  /r:1 /w:2 /xo
```

This is make all folders to contain the last modification files.

- `/xo` - Do not overwrite old files over new files.
- `/r:1 /w:s` - Repeat only one time (and wait 2 seconds, before retried)