# What is the easiest way to sync the contents of two folders on windows?

Tags: windows, sync, user-folders

Pure windows solutions such as cmd or task scheduler are preferred. I want to sync the contents of two folders without changing their names. I would like to know ways to sync them one-way and two-way (One-way the first time, because one is more recently-updated than the other, and two-way after).

Comment: While not free (however inexpensive), I use Sync Back Pro. It does all of the above with ease and aplomb and in particular - one way (back up) and two way (sync). I prefer this to a weaker command method as it has more options and is fully supported.

Comment: Try robocopy : https://superuser.com/a/845198

Answer (score 0):

Create a script which copies files back and forth, e.g.
xcopy /e source destination
robocopy /e source destination

robocopy is newer and more advanced copy tool, it even has a built in file change monitoring /MON parameter.