# How does SyncBack detect if two files are different?

Tags: sync, mirroring, syncback

I'm currently using SyncBack's free version, SyncBackFree, to mirror files from a LAN directory to a directory in my PC, after reading this SU post: [How can I keep folders synchronized between several machines over my home network?](https://superuser.com/q/349/10259)

I would like to know how SyncBack compares two files to know if they are different, if at default settings, when mirroring files to another directory. Is it by modification/access/etc. date? By size? By checksum? At what order? At what amount of difference will it consider two files different? If it happens to use a hash algorithm, it would be good to know which one it uses too.

I'm asking because I would like to know how accurate (at what point will it consider two files different) and how fast is the performance (how many or which comparison tests does it do) of SyncBack's file similarity detection feature.

I'm currently using SyncBackFree v6.5.15.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: It is very unlikely that anyone on here is going to know anything about a proprietary hash algorithm used in closed source software.

Comment: @MaQleod I'm more interested in learning if it uses a hash algorithm at all rather than knowing what exact hash algorithm is used. Although if that has been posted by a developer somewhere, that could be useful additional information. e.g. Is it CRC32? (common in other file similarity detecting software). I'm mainly interested in knowing how it compares files (By modification date? By size? By checksum? At what order? At what amount of difference will it consider two files different?). If it happens to use a hash algorithm that would be good to know too.